# In Powershell 2.0, how do I create a GUI that not only displays text, but can take input for the script?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I'm creating a powershell script to reset passwords on AD. My goal is to create a little GUI interface that runs real time that can not only display text but take input, as well as display new results (maybe a possible execute button as well). Is this possible? I've been googling on how to do it, but I must not have the correct terminology, as I am getting irrelevant search results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Here is an answer to a very similiar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18829164/775544) that describes what you will need to get started. The code example in the answer should help you to get a foundation to get your mind around the problem, and the link offers a working example.  A note for site usage: Generally, you will want to be further along in the process to ask questions here -- to a point where you can describe specific problems you're facing, or offer examples of code that isn't working.

Comment: I give an answer in [Create a GUI front end for Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17843211/608772)